# Consume Organization.svc with SOAP authentication with Web Application Proxy

Tags: soap, dynamics-crm, adfs, pre-authentication

We have a CRM Dynamics 2016 onpremise (IFD configured), we access to the CRM from a Cordova mobile application via SOAP authentication and consume the service "Organization.svc" to get or set Data: everything works fine until now.
After adding a Web Application Proxy, the call to ADFS for the token still working, and returns a valid token. However, the second step of consuming the service "Organization.svc" is blocked : the Web Application Proxy redirects the call to the ADFS login page, which is of course not what I want.
I think the root of the problem is in the fact that the proxy cannot 'read' the SAML token I'm sending in my HTTPRequest.
Did anyone have an idea how to resolve that ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you maybe inspect with Fiddler if the proxy is forwarding the required authentication cookies / headers ? I presume these are ignored by the proxy and ADFS sees the second request as not authenticated.

Comment: Thank you Jordi. In the proxy, I find this error: "Web Application Proxy received a request with an expired access cookie", I verify time on proxy and ADFS and there are synchronized.